# Trying to add error bars to a line graph on R but get an error message

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am following the instructions from the R cookbook graphics page 159 and I am trying to add error bars to a line graph but get an error message the code is the following:

```
gplot(SMCSO1, aes(x=Vegetables, y=Avg.Val))
>       geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Avg.Val-sd, ymax=Avg.Val+sd), 
+                     width=.2, colour="black") +
+                    geom_line() +
+                   geom_point()

Error in geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Avg.Val - sd, ymax = Avg.Val + sd),  : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I have managed to successfully add error bars on a bar plot but can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Many thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

If this is exactly the way you are passing commands to R, you are missing a + at the end of the first line.

Comment: Many thanks Roman, much appreciated. I did actually figure out yesterday evening